# My object displays wireframe in 3d view. How to make it solid?

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

I just want to make every object solid and don't care if there is the anser to the question or not.

Comment: Could you tell a bit more about how the "non solid" object has been made? What have you tried so far? Could you also ceck the title? I'm not sure about what is it saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to solve it I guess:

- You're in the ***Wireframe*** display mode and need to cange it to ***Solid***.

  [image]
- You've *Maximum Draw Type* set to ***Wire*** and need to change it to ***Textured*** and *uncheck* ***Wire*** and ***Draw All Edges*** boxes (if present).

  [image: List item]